# Solving differential equations in Hilbert and Sobolev spaces

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Given the differential equation
$$
 \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2y + |x|, \forall (x, y) \in [-4, 4] \times [-4, 4].
$$
 Explain, with calculations, why the differential equation has no solutions in Hilbert space but rather in the Sobolev spaces.

I have done the calculations, but I don't know how to relate it to Hilbert and Sobolev spaces. I have no idea about how to do differential equations in Hilbert and Sobolev spaces. Can someone help show me how to answer this question? Also, can anyone suggest a good reference for solving differential equations in Hilbert and Sobolev spaces?

Comment: This is just $\mathbb R$, so the computation is trivial. What did you try?

Comment: @John B. I did the calculation, but what I don't understand is how to related that to Hilbert ans Sobolev spaces.

Comment: I don't understand the question, so much so that I feel like you and I call different things "hilbert spaces" and "sobolev spaces"?

Comment: Great, once you show us the calculations we should be able to see how to relate this to weak derivatives.