# On an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me that how to solve the ode $$y'=2y+|x| $$
for all $(x,y)$ member of $[-4,4] \times [-4,4].$

$y'-2y=|x|$  now this the first order differential equation .
       compare with $y'+p(x)y=q(x)$
      then $p(x) =-2$ then integrating factor is $e^{-2x}$
       then after that I am unable to work.please help me thanku

Comment: Same comment as for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706718/solving-differential-equations-in-hilbert-and-sobolev-spaces#comment7618086_3706718, although you can note that $(e^{-2x}y)'=e^{-2x}|x|$.

Comment: So how we go to the solution .y(x)=e^(2x) integration of (e^(-2x))|x| is a solution or not?please explain